# Can't connect to jupyter server in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My settings file looks like this

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/username/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
}
```

And I can see the conda environment in the interpreter that I'd like to activate from vscode interpreter selections but whenever I try to run the a cell in vscode I get a long error message.

```
Activating Python 3.7.7 64-bit ('myenv': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: Command failed: . activate myenv && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.105369/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.105369/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py bash: activate: No such file or directory .
```

I chdecked my $PATH variable and it each directory existed in it. (Looks like how other stack questions suggested it should look as well)

What am I missing? I had it working on a similar machine a couple weeks ago but I can't seem to get it to work now.

I'm on `Ubuntu 20.04` if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely familiar with the issue, but some digging around lead me to this, try these settings

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": ""
}
```

If that doesn't work please reference this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5145). They seem to be experiencing the same issue as you, but on windows. You may be able to extract more information from it than I could. Sorry if this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around quite a bit, I made a new environment and it worked. I'm not sure what I did within that environment to make vscode unhappy with it but vscode didn't like something about it.

Before making the new environment I also ran a few commands including
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.conda`
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/miniconda3`
`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

I'm not sure what got it to work but I'm happy it's working now!